# How can I move the following trigger logic into an apex class?

Tags: apex, class

How can I move the following trigger logic into an apex class?

```
trigger AssignAccNumber on Opportunity(before insert,before update){

List<Id> accIds = new List<Id>();

for(Opportunity opp:trigger.new){

    if(opp.AccountId!=null){

        accIds.add(opp.AccountId);
    }
}

Map<Id,Account> accMap = new Map<Id,Account>([SELECT id,Area__c,AccountNumber,Type FROM Account WHERE id in:accIds]);
Account a = [SELECT AccountNumber FROM Account WHERE AccountNumber != null AND Type='Prospect' AND Area__c='East' ORDER BY AccountNumber DESC LIMIT 1];

for(Opportunity opp :Trigger.new){
 Account accs = accMap.get(opp.AccountId);       

if(!accMap.IsEmpty()){

        if(opp.Probability == 95 && accs.AccountNumber == null){

            if(accs.LC_Market__c == 'Americas' && accs.Type == 'Prospect'){

                accs.AccountNumber = String.valueOf(Integer.valueOf(a.AccountNumber)+1);
            }            
        }
        update accMap.values();
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

You only need to pass the Opportunities from the new trigger to the new class

```
public class NameOfClass {
         List<Opportunity> triggerOpps = new List<Opportunity>();
         List<Id> accIds = new List<Id>();

         public NameOfClass(List<Opportunity> opps){
                 triggerOpps = opps;
         }

         for(Opportunity opp: triggerOpps ){
                if(opp.AccountId!=null){
                      accIds.add(opp.AccountId);
                }
         }

         Map<Id,Account> accMap = new Map<Id,Account>([SELECT id,Area__c,AccountNumber,Type FROM Account WHERE id in:accIds]);
         Account a = [SELECT AccountNumber FROM Account WHERE AccountNumber != null AND Type='Prospect' AND Area__c='East' ORDER BY AccountNumber DESC LIMIT 1];

         for(Opportunity opp :Trigger.new){
                 Account accs = accMap.get(opp.AccountId);       

                 if(!accMap.IsEmpty()){
                     if(opp.Probability == 95 && accs.AccountNumber == null){

                          if(accs.LC_Market__c == 'Americas' && accs.Type == 'Prospect'){
                                 accs.AccountNumber = String.valueOf(Integer.valueOf(a.AccountNumber)+1);
                          }            
                      }
                      update accMap.values();
                  }
          }

}
```

And in your trigger:

```
trigger AssignAccNumber on Opportunity(before insert,before update){
        NameOfClass noc = new NameOfClass(trigger.new);
}
```

Or you might want to wrap your trigger logic in a method that is inside the newly created apex class

```
public class NameOfClass {
       List<Id> accIds = new List<Id>();

       public void Execute(List<Opportunity> opps){
            for(Opportunity opp: triggerOpps ){
                 if(opp.AccountId!=null){
                        accIds.add(opp.AccountId);
            }


             Map<Id,Account> accMap = new Map<Id,Account>([SELECT id,Area__c,AccountNumber,Type FROM Account WHERE id in:accIds]);
             Account a = [SELECT AccountNumber FROM Account WHERE AccountNumber != null AND Type='Prospect' AND Area__c='East' ORDER BY AccountNumber DESC LIMIT 1];

             for(Opportunity opp :Trigger.new){
                     Account accs = accMap.get(opp.AccountId);       

                     if(!accMap.IsEmpty()){
                         if(opp.Probability == 95 && accs.AccountNumber == null){

                              if(accs.LC_Market__c == 'Americas' && accs.Type == 'Prospect'){
                                     accs.AccountNumber = String.valueOf(Integer.valueOf(a.AccountNumber)+1);
                              }            
                          }
                          update accMap.values();
                      }
              }
        }                        
    }
```

And then call the method from the trigger

```
trigger AssignAccNumber on Opportunity(before insert,before update){
            NameOfClass noc = new NameOfClass();
            noc.Execute(trigger.new);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Kon,

Force.com MVP Kevin O'Hara has created a framework to handle exactly this.  Visit his github project here: https://github.com/kevinohara80/sfdc-trigger-framework.  Follow the instructions in the README and you'll find moving your logic outside of your trigger isn't as complicated as you may think.